# Web Services client generation using Apache Axis2 1.7.8

Tags: java, soap

I have generated web clients for `SOAP` web services using `Apache Axis2 1.7.8`
And I have written the below `CustomStub` class which the `stub` class extends/inherits.

```
public class CustomStub extends Stub {

protected AxisService _service;
protected ArrayList modules = new ArrayList();


protected ServiceClient _serviceClient;

/**
 * Get service client implementation used by this stub.
 *
 * @return service client
 */
public ServiceClient _getServiceClient() {
    return _serviceClient;
}

/**
 * Set service client implementation used by this stub. Once set, the
 * service client is owned by this stub and will automatically be removed
 * from the configuration when use of the stub is done.
 *
 * @param _serviceClient
 */
public void _setServiceClient(ServiceClient _serviceClient) {
    this._serviceClient = _serviceClient;
}

/**
 * Create a SOAP message envelope using the supplied options.
 * TODO generated stub code should use this method, or similar method taking
 * an operation client
 *
 * @param options
 * @return generated
 * @throws SOAPProcessingException
 */
protected static SOAPEnvelope createEnvelope(Options options) throws SOAPProcessingException {
    return getFactory(options.getSoapVersionURI()).getDefaultEnvelope();
}

/**
 * Get Axiom factory appropriate to selected SOAP version.
 *
 * @param soapVersionURI
 * @return factory
 */
protected static SOAPFactory getFactory(String soapVersionURI) {

    if (SOAP11Constants.SOAP_ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI.equals(soapVersionURI)) {
        return OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory();
    } else if (SOAP12Constants.SOAP_ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI.equals(soapVersionURI)) {
        return OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP12Factory();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(Messages
                .getMessage("unknownsoapversion"));
    }
}

/**
 * Finalize method called by garbage collection. This is overridden to
 * support cleanup of any associated resources.
 *
 * @throws Throwable
 */
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    super.finalize();
    cleanup();
}

/**
 * Cleanup associated resources. This removes the axis service from the
 * configuration.
 *
 * @throws AxisFault
 */
public void cleanup() throws AxisFault {
    // service is removed from the service client it self.
    _serviceClient.cleanup();
}

/**
 * sets the epr of the service client to given value
 *
 * @param address
 */

protected void setServiceClientEPR(String address) {
    EndpointReference toEPRFromServiceClient = _serviceClient.getOptions().getTo();
    toEPRFromServiceClient.setAddress(address);
}

/**
 * add an http header with name and value to message context
 *
 * @param messageContext
 * @param name
 * @param value
 */
protected void addHttpHeader(MessageContext messageContext,
                             String name,
                             String value) {
    java.lang.Object headersObj = messageContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS);
    if (headersObj == null) {
        headersObj = new java.util.ArrayList();
    }
    java.util.List headers = (java.util.List) headersObj;
    Header header = new Header();
    header.setName(name);
    header.setValue(value);
    headers.add(header);
    messageContext.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, headers);
}

/**
 * sets the propertykey and propertyValue as a pair to operation client
 *
 * @param operationClient
 * @param propertyKey
 * @param propertyValue
 */

protected void addPropertyToOperationClient(OperationClient operationClient,
                                            String propertyKey,
                                            Object propertyValue) {
    operationClient.getOptions().setProperty(propertyKey, propertyValue);
}

protected void addPropertyToOperationClient(OperationClient operationClient,
                                            String propertyKey,
                                            boolean value) {
    addPropertyToOperationClient(operationClient, propertyKey, new Boolean(value));
}

protected void addPropertyToOperationClient(OperationClient operationClient,
                                            String propertyKey,
                                            int value) {
    addPropertyToOperationClient(operationClient, propertyKey, new Integer(value));
}

protected void setMustUnderstand(OMElement headerElement, OMNamespace omNamespace) {
    OMFactory omFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMAttribute mustUnderstandAttribute =
            omFactory.createOMAttribute(SOAP12Constants.ATTR_MUSTUNDERSTAND, omNamespace,
                                        "true");
    headerElement.addAttribute(mustUnderstandAttribute);
}

protected void addHeader(OMElement omElementToadd,
                         SOAPEnvelope envelop,
                         boolean mustUnderstand){
    SOAPHeaderBlock soapHeaderBlock =
            envelop.getHeader().addHeaderBlock(omElementToadd.getLocalName(),omElementToadd.getNamespace());
   // soapHeaderBlock.setMustUnderstand(mustUnderstand);
    OMNode omNode = null;

    // add child elements
    Iterator children = omElementToadd.getChildElements();
    while (children.hasNext()) {
   // for (Iterator iter = omElementToadd.getChildren(); iter.hasNext();){
         omNode = (OMNode) children.next();
         soapHeaderBlock.addChild(omNode);
    }

    OMAttribute omatribute = null;
    // add attributes
    for (Iterator iter = omElementToadd.getAllAttributes(); iter.hasNext();){
         omatribute = (OMAttribute) iter.next();
         soapHeaderBlock.addAttribute(omatribute);
    }

}

protected void addHeader(OMElement omElementToadd,
                         SOAPEnvelope envelop){
    addHeader(omElementToadd,envelop,false);
}

protected void addAnonymousOperations(){
    RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation robustoutoonlyOperation =
            new RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation(ServiceClient.ANON_ROBUST_OUT_ONLY_OP);
    _service.addOperation(robustoutoonlyOperation);

    OutOnlyAxisOperation outOnlyOperation = new OutOnlyAxisOperation(ServiceClient.ANON_OUT_ONLY_OP);
    _service.addOperation(outOnlyOperation);

    OutInAxisOperation outInOperation = new OutInAxisOperation(ServiceClient.ANON_OUT_IN_OP);
    _service.addOperation(outInOperation);
}

}
```

But when I am invoking the web service , I am getting the below error :

**log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axiom.locator.DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: The current node has been removed using a method other than Iterator#remove()
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:67)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMFilterIterator.hasNext(OMFilterIterator.java:54)
    at org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide.CustomStub.addHeader(CustomStub.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide.CustomStub.addHeader(CustomStub.java:217)
    at org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide.TripolisPublishingServiceStub.tripolisPublishEmail(TripolisPublishingServiceStub.java:218)
    at com.abnamro.Driver.main(Driver.java:38)**

Answer (score 0):

When you call addChild on an OMElement the method changes the parent of the node being added as child.
In addHeader block of your code when you call addChild(omNode) you are changing the parent of omNode to soapHeaderBlock. So the next hasNext call fails saying that the original structure has been modified.

Try this instead :

```
Iterator children = omElementToadd.getChildElements();
while (children.hasNext()) {
     omNode = (OMNode) children.next();
     OMElement clonedEl = omNode.cloneOMElement();
     soapHeaderBlock.addChild(clonedEl);
}
```